# "Like" open graph action

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have an iPhone app (http://getnowapp.com) that lets you "Like an experience".
I would like to integrate it on the Facebook timeline with Open Graph.

I set up the "Like" action on Opengraph but got rejected with the following reason:
"Your Action failed the criteria: You are trying to submit a custom action which is not permitted. Please delete this action and submit a built-in version of this action instead."

So it seems Like is not an acceptable action as it already exists in Facebook.

However, you can "Like a Pin on Pinterest" without any issues.

Am i missing something here?

Thanks!
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you figured out, "like" action is already defined by facebook and that's why you can't define a new one.
I guess what pinterest does is to use the like connection that is already supported by Open Graph API to "Like." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#like_action
I'm not quite sure because I haven't used this action, though.

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/ACTION_ID/likes?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

And just in case you are interested, you can see some insights of pinterest's implementation. [here](https://developers.facebook.com/showcase/pinterest/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What puzzles me is that Pinterest redefines a "like" action.. "like a pin". What you are talking about is liking an instance of an action. not actually sending an action "like". I guess they had a special treatment from Facebook..

Comment: On top of the fact that Pinterest is able to "Like a pin", "like" is actually given as an example for OG actions.. no? http://cl.ly/2P0T2S2w2g1t1N252v2W I feel like I'm missing something here!

Comment: You might wanna check this out. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/06/20/bringing-like-to-mobile/ They are now providing a built-in like action!
They say "we will no longer approve custom like actions. Apps that currently use a custom like action must migrate to..." So people could develop own "like" action like you talked about pinterest and now it's prohibited. Maybe that's why you couldn't have it.
but now you can use built-in action to "like" something.